# Prove that for an associative algebraic structure, the inverse of every invertible element is unique.

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups, algebraic-groups, semigroups

I don't know how to start this prove. For a group, it's easy to prove. Like we can start with
Let e be an identity element. Suppose a belongs to G(where G is a group) and b,b' belongs to G are the inverse of the element a.
now a*e=e*a=b and a*e=e*a=b'
But I don't know how to start for semigroup.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $b$ is the inverse of $a$ means
$$
ab=ba=e
$$
and *not* that $ae=ea=b$.

If $b'$ is another inverse of $a$, then
$$
b'=eb'=(ba)b'
$$
Now continue using associativity.

Comment: But how then $0\cdot\infty=0$ but $1/\infty=0$?

Comment: @Anixx What algebraic structure are you talking about?

Comment: Extended real line.

Comment: @Anixx Is $\infty$ invertible? Is $0$ invertible?

Comment: $\infty$ is invertible because $1/\infty=0$. $0$ is either invertible or not depending on compactification type (in projective compactification, invertible).

Comment: @Anixx What's your definition of invertible element? Mine is “$a$ is invertible if there exists $b$ such that $ab=1$” and this is what I used in the answer. Of course you're free to define “invertible” in a different way, but you can't expect the same theorems proved with the common definition to hold for *your* definition.

Comment: Mine is "by which we can divide".

Comment: So you're in a structure with *two* operations. A very different situation, with a very different definition..